# Strike price confusion

Tags: call-options

I am reading a document that says `The seller of 10 call options, with a strike price of 400 at CHF 8.00, (contract value 10), has the following risk`

What does `400 at CHF 8` mean? i.e. I understand what 8 Swiss Francs mean but what is this 400 doing?

Comment: What type of options are these? I'm a bit confuses because it seems to indicate a different price paid than a market value, so I'm wondering if these are FX or some other option.

Comment: It is nowhere specified what type of options is this. So I assume this applies to the most common or generic one's

Answer (score 0):

400 is the strike price for the call option, that is, the amount the person who exercises the option has to pay for each share of stock they call.

Comment: Cool but what means the 8 CHF?

Comment: You stated in your question that `I understand what 8 Swiss Francs mean.`  And now you no longer understand what 8 CHFs is?

Comment: @Curiousmoneyperson I'd have to see the rest of the statement to know. I suspect it means the sale price of the option.

Comment: @david that's all, there is no extra context.

Comment: @bob I understand what 8 Swiss Francs mean, in general. Not what 400 at 8.00 CHF mean.

Comment: @Curiousmoneyperson So "has the following risk" doesn't refer to anything following?

Answer (score -1):

The strike price is the price at which a derivative contract can be bought or sold when it is exercised.

For call options, the strike price is what the owner pays for the  security if he exercises his call.  The counterparty  who is short the call and is assigned receives that amount.

For put options, the strike price is the price at which the owner sells the security for if he exercises his put. The counterparty who is short the put and is assigned pays that amount.

Strike price is also known as the exercise price.

Comment: Unrelated to my question